# jQuery resistance on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

So I got a code that works well. I got a full screen slider first on my page.
Right now if I scroll down it animates me past the slider and if I go up it animates me to the top of the page, seeing the slider.

Now I want some resistance when I scroll, like there's a barrier I have to break before it animates down. If I don't break it, it snaps back to its original position.

Any suggestion on what I should do?

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var scrollReady = 1;
jQuery(window).scroll(function(event){

    if (scrollReady == 1) {
        var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();

        var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrollTop){
            // downscroll code

            if (st < winHeight) {
                // is at slider scrolling down

                // RESISTANCE CODE
                if (notBrokenBarrier) {
                    // Resistance before breaking barrier
                    // Some thing like this? maybe?
                    jQuery(this).scrollTop() / 4;

                    // Some setTimeout for snapping back
                } else {
                    // Broke barrier, scroll down.
                    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: winHeight + "px" }, animationSpeed);
                    scrollReady = 0;
                    setTimeout(function(){scrollReady = 1;}, animationSpeed);
                }
            }
        } else if (st < lastScrollTop) {
            // upscroll code
            if (st < winHeight) {
                // scroll up to the slider
                jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, animationSpeed);

                scrollReady = 0;
                setTimeout(function(){scrollReady = 1;}, (animationSpeed+500));
            }
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/lowuqiquji/1/edit?js,console,output

So the animation goes quite good, scrolling past the slider on down, and up to top when you scroll up. I want some resistance in this action, making it a bit harder to execute to scroll past it.

Comment: yeh, let me try to create a jsbin with it just a sec

Comment: Awesome! I'll wait :)

Comment: ok tried to help! have a look in the console to understand